# Default onClick event or fromEvent(button, 'click')

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am studing Rxjs, and in most onclick event based examples they use `fromEvent` handler, is it mandatory to use `fromEvent`, as we have adapted to onClick binding on the html tags from very early

ex: `<button onClick="printMe(e)">Print</button>`

some.js

```
function printMe(e){
   console.log(e)
}
```

But to do the same thing in Rxjs we have to do these many lines of code.

[image: fromEvent]

I understand that in Rxjs we deal most of the time with Observables, and we need to create a Observable on the button, So we write this line

```
// create an observable of button clicks
const myObservable = fromEvent(button, 'click');
```

But this looks too much codeing for a simple click event handling, 
Putting My question in simple terms

Do we always use/adapt `fromEvent` while codeing in Rxjs, and should not use OnClick, OnFocus,( On* ) Any more ?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** answer to "Do we always use/adapt fromEvent while coding in Rxjs":

No

RxJS gives utility and we should use it when it suitable. The code could become a mess if you would do every button event this way.

As for `fromEvent` - it could be suitable for some global *side-effects* plus read [official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) for more understanding